# C# do (not) call event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling

I am quite new to this and I am building an easy app in visual studio in C# which is plotting graphs and user can customize them by using checkboxes and radiobuttons. These are linked to events and when checkstate is changed, the event is called and the code do its job. But these events are called even when the checkstate was not changed and all plotted areas reload multiple times which is not very pleasant to the user. Can you please advise me how to call the event only when it is required. It's WinForms. An example is below. I want to display the output in both cases - if the bool value is true or false, the output is dependent on this and the outcome is different.

`

```
private void CheckBoxCountInvalid_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBoxCountInvalid.Checked)
                countInvalid = true;
            else
                countInvalid = false;
            ShowOutput();
        }
```

`

Comment: You'll probably need to provide some of the code in question and clarify what type of application you have created such as WebForms, MVC, Blazor...

Comment: Why your `ShowOutput();` method is not `ShowOutput(bool state);`? Then just pass `ShowOutput(checkBoxCountInvalid.Checked);`. Do note that RadioButtons (not CheckBoxes) change state when you select another RadioButton in the Group.

Answer (score 1):

An (if else) sounds like if would work fine for that problem.

Comment: In this case I would need a condition which would tell me whether the state was changed, if it's checked or not is not enough here. The graphs are rendered in both cases and the bool tells the code whether to render all values or just the valid ones.